# Software Development without Continuous Integration

Tags: git, continuous-integration, workflow

Endorsement of Continuous Integration so overwhelms discourse on software development methodology that I have not been able to find anything online to recommend an alternative approach.

The problem with Continuous Integration I am looking to avoid is the difficulty incurred by removing a feature. E.g., two features have been developed independently. Using Continuous Integration, feature A would be merged to the mainline, then feature B would be sync'd with the mainline, integrating feature A. If it is later decided feature B is to be released without feature A, feature A must be extracted from feature B. This can be further complicated by synchronizations necessitated by additional changes to feature A and integrations with additional features.

One approach would be to have a branch where features are integrated without first being synchronized with the integration branch. Instead of extracting a feature, the integration branch is simply recreated without the feature to be excluded. This approach introduces nuances to conflict resolution not present in Continuous Integration, such as repeating conflict resolutions the same way upon recreation of the integration branch.

I am hoping to find established workflows that have already addressed these concerns - preferably using git and ideally using GitHub.

If anyone in the Stack Overflow community can direct me to such a workflow it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in software development that overwhelms everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflows are customized by different development teams to accommodate the needs of your development team(s), software technologies and platforms being used, stakeholders, deployment schedule(s), financial and time budget, and a variety of other factors. Providing a specific recommendation to you would require a deeper understanding of your needs--beyond continuous integration and being able to roll-back a specific already-merged feature. Making recommendations based on the information you already provided will likely lead to follow-up considerations, providing substantial opportunity for extended pros/cons dialogue. There surely is no single answer to your question.

So rather than trying to provide one, I'd instead like to recommend an overview of some prevailing team-oriented Git-workflow strategies. Please consider this as a useful starting point:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: I have read these pages before. But I had at the time inferred that they presumed a feature is synchronized with upstream changes before being integrated. On re-reading them with the intent to cite that presumption I see it was in fact my own. So, instead of looking for alternatives to CI, I can now focus on searching for a workflow that facilitates feature extraction. I do not see that specifically addressed in those models but I expect better search results by not even mentioning CI.

Comment: Excellent start, Ken. I'm sure you'll find other good resources once you identify more specific needs/scenarios you're trying to address.